# How to edit html classes inline?

Tags: html, wysiwyg

lets say you have html like this,

```
<span class="full-sentence">
<span class="subject">She</span><span class="verb">loves</span><span class="object">him</span>
.</span>
```

What the user sees is,

```
She loves him.
```

Using a wysiwyg HTML inline editor, you could change the "She loves him." string into something else, like "He loves her coat." for example, but you would have no way of adding the span class "noun" to the word coat in the wysiwyg editor without displaying the source code to some extent.

I'm trying to find a way to do this, first by displaying the span classes text, such as "verb" from the , display the "verb" string in the output, and allowing it to be changed inline, and have it transform the string inside the sourcecode right inside the parenthesis of class=""

I'm trying to accomplish this WITHOUT displaying anything irrelevant, such as the `<span class=""></span>` characters. All the user really needs to work with is the spot inside the `""` marks, the text itself, and have the ability to add new span class boundaries, by highlighting a string and pressing some kind of button that wraps that highlighted string in `<span class=""></span>` and then allows you to write classes to fill the `""`.

It would ideally look something like this, without the awkward spacing between text strings as in a libreoffice writer table, which this is a picture of,
[image: http://i.imgur.com/2x8c5OF.png]

![enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 0):

The default [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) shows parent elements in the bottom bar, and permits right click to edit properties of select elements. You could use a bar or a mouseover to edit and display the word type, and you would also want some cleanup code for when people paste html and join two words etc.
From a technical perspective it's relatively trivial once you are clear on the interface you want to make your own custom WYSIWYG.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    Editable text...
</div>
```